# How to use css3 flexbox to place post list on left and google maps canvas on right colum?

Tags: html, css

How to use new css3 properties for example flexbox to split view to two columns, so that left column with posts list that would have scroll overflow-y to the page bottom and maps container that will fill its container and stay permanently on right side?

```js
var post = "<h3>Post title</h3><div>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</div><hr>";
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
  $('#left_container').append(post);
  i++;
}

var options = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(49, 17),
  scrollwheel: false
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);
```

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.flexbox-container #left_container {
  width: 35vw;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 100vp;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.flexbox-container #map_container {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
#map_canvas {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 65vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>

<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div id="left_container"></div>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/290/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div id="left_container">
    <div class="container-content">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flexbox-container {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flexbox-container #left_container {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.container-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flexbox-container #map_container {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
  flex: 2;
}
```

Comment: I've disabled scroll wheel on google maps [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/291/), How can I scroll posts list on scrolling above maps?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean?

Comment: In attached example, when I'm trying to scroll over the map canvas I would like to scroll left container, could you tell me how can I accomplish it?

Comment: I don't think there is way to do that with just css and you will have to use js.